# How to detect cancel event through javascript when user click on cancel button on popup on safari browser to open deeplink from web browser?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I want to execute a function when user click on the cancel button. As the popup is generated by IOS itself so I am not able to get exact element name/class? So, if any know how to access the cancel element then kindly guide me.

Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Thanks!
Robin[image]

Comment: Hi All, I got an update that its not possible to control the popup as it's an OS dialog you can't just control. (refer to: https://github.com/hampusohlsson/browser-deeplink/issues/16)